# Creating new formula with one extra variable in R

Tags: r, rstudio, formula

So I would like to created a new formula in R based on another formula, the difference should only be in one additional variable:

For example I have:

```
formula = as.formula(price ~ speed + hp + mpg)
formula2 = as.formula(paste0(format(formula), "+ factor(DEPARTMENT)-1"))
```

However Code is not working the results I want is:
`formula2 = price ~ speed + hp + mpg + factor(DEPARTMENT0) -1`

Answer (score 0):

`?update.formula` seems to be exactly what you are looking for !

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/update.formula.html